# Institute name in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am trying to put the name of the institution in a beamer presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\institution{XYZ}
...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

However I get the error that it is an `undefined control sequence`. What possibly is the mistake?

Comment: I just got the same problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The right command is `\institute{...}` (see as reference the `beameruserguide` section 10.1 Adding a Title Page).

A better way to proceed is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
...
\end{document}
```